# How to Mock Handler(Looper) on kotlin unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, handler, postdelayed

```
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
            {
                println("inside the looper")
                val firmwareVersion = managerService.getDeviceFirmwareVersion();
                fwStatus = if (!firmwareVersion.isNullOrEmpty()) "$versionValue $firmwareVersion" else "--"
                UpdateManagerInstance.disconnectFromUpdateService()
            }, 2000)
```

is there anyway to tackle this block of code on Unit test kotlin mockito?

Comment: manage to solve this issue, using MockContructor method to tackle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android unit testing, you might need to mock the **Handler** or **Looper** to test code that involves background threads or delayed operations. Here's how you can mock a **Handler** and **Looper** in Kotlin unit tests:

1. **Use a Testing Framework:** To mock a **Handler** and **Looper** effectively, you can use a testing framework like Mockito, which allows you to create mock objects. To use Mockito in your Android project, you need to include the Mockito dependency in your project's **build.gradle** file:

> test implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:x.y.z'

Replace 'x.y.z' with the latest version of Mockito available.

1. **Mocking Handler and Looper:**
   Assuming you have a class with a **Handler** or Looper dependency that you want to test, you can mock these objects in your unit test. For example, let's say you have a class with a Handler dependency:

> ```
> class MyHandlerClass(private val handler: Handler) {
>     // Your code that uses the Handler
> }
> ```

In your unit test, you can mock the **Handler** using Mockito:

```
import android.os.Handler
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito

class MyHandlerClassTest {
    @Test
    fun testHandlerFunction() {
        // Create a mock Handler
        val handler = Mockito.mock(Handler::class.java)

        // Create an instance of your class with the mock Handler
        val myHandlerClass = MyHandlerClass(handler)

        // Your test logic here
    }
}
```

By creating a mock **Handler** with Mockito, you can control its behavior during your tests.

1. **Mocking Looper:**
   If your code directly depends on the **Looper**, you can mock the **Looper** as well. Here's an example:

> ```
> import android.os.Handler
> import android.os.Looper
> import org.junit.Test
> import org.mockito.Mockito
>
> class MyLooperClassTest {
>     @Test
>     fun testLooperFunction() {
>         // Create a mock Looper
>         val looper = Mockito.mock(Looper::class.java)
>
>         // Create a mock Handler with the mock Looper
>         val handler = Handler(looper)
>
>         // Create an instance of your class with the mock Handler
>         val myLooperClass = MyHandlerClass(handler)
>
>         // Your test logic here
>     }
> }
> ```

Mocking the **Looper** in this way allows you to control the behavior of the Handler since **Handler** relies on the provided Looper.

Remember that Mockito allows you to define the behavior of these mock objects by using its when and thenReturn methods. This way, you can simulate the expected behavior of the **Handler** or **Looper** during your unit tests.

Comment: `val looper = mockk<Looper>(relaxed = true)
        val mockRunnable = mockk<Runnable>(relaxed = true)
        // Create a mock Handler with the mock Looper
        val handler = Handler(looper)
        every {
            handler.postDelayed(mockRunnable, anyLong())
        } returns true` 

i mock this way but i am getting Missing calls inside every{} block error, don't seem to undertstand why

Comment: on my case the handler is not a class object is there any way to mock it?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample UseCase**

```
 val handler = mock(Handler::class.java)
`when`(handler.post(any())).thenAnswer { invocation ->
                invocation.getArgument(0, Runnable::class.java).run()
                true
 }
```